# Cyrillic text appears garbled in the VisualStudio.com web interface

Tags: git, character-encoding, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using visualstudio.com git to store my source code, and now it screws up Ukrainian text and instead of:

```
WithSuccess("Збережено");
```

I am getting smt like that:

```
WithSuccess("Çáåðåæåíî");
```

I am not sure where is the problem us on my local PC everything looks good and only after pushing commits I can see that on web it's changed.

Is there any configuration that helps solve this problem?

Comment: Is the code been changed, or is the web access unable to display it correctly?

Comment: code has been changed as after updating sources to the latest on other machine I am getting spaghetti instead of Cyrillic text. Or maybe my machine is configured in a such a way that it can handle Cyrillic but other machine can't, but I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

> ... I can see that on web it's changed.

The problem is that there's no meta-information attached to files stored in a Git repository which would hint *a renderer* (in your case—that web site engine which renders the content of your file) in which encoding the file is encoded.  Git most of the time treats what it stores as opaque binaries, and encodings only come to consideration in some of its UI parts (`git log`, `gitk`, `git gui`).

So to see what part misbehaves, *clone* your pushed repository afresh to some other place (on your local PC) and check the contents of the files containing Cyrillic text. If you see everything is OK, then just live with this or file a feature request against that online service for it to support user-specific encoding hints—like the `gui.encoding` configuration variable used by certain Git tools—so that you could specify what encoding the files in your repository are supposed to be in.

Comment: @bats-ihor, just from the look of the text you showed, I'd say you have your file encoded in Windows-1251 and the web page renderer assumed it's Latin-1 (Windows-1252).  Since the lower 127 characters in these encoding tables are the same, ASCII text is not garbled.

Comment: From his reply to my comment asking if this was the case: *code has been changed as after updating sources to the latest on other machine I am getting spaghetti instead of Cyrillic text. Or maybe my machine is configured in a such a way that it can handle Cyrillic but other machine can't, but I don't think so...*

Comment: Yes the problem is not only in browser, after downloading the code I get screwed up text as mentioned below.

Comment: @BatsIhor, OK since the repository you push to *is not supposed to* change the objects sent into it, the problem *should* be with your local setup.  So at first please read [this manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) and try to see if you have a `.gitattributes` file somewhere in your project tree or the `attributes` file under the `.git\info` directory in your project directory.  If you happen to have any such file, it might define a `clean` filter or an `encoding` directive which might be used by VS.

Comment: @BatsIhor, the second thing to check is to try to verify *plain* commits -- bypassing whatever machinery VS uses to commit to Git -- work.  For this, you need plain [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) (be sure to tick the box "Make Git available in the Windows command shell" when installing). Once you have it installed and working (running `git --version` in a console prompt should print the Git's version string), `cd` to the project's directory, create a simple text file there (save it in Windows-1251 -- called "ANSI" in Notepad) and commit it: `git add thatfile.cs` + `git commit`.

Comment: @BatsIhor, then verify you have this file's contents not garbled when committing: you can do this by running `git show HEAD:thatfile.cs >out.cs` -- this would extract the contents `thatfile.cs` from the tip commit and save it to a file named `out.cs` (creating it or overwriting if it exists).  Then inspect the resulting file and see if it has Cyrillic text garbled.  If yes, VS must be modifying your files somehow before they're committed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't resolved issue yet but I hav foung the workaround, I use Notepad++ to change encoding of the file and it helps. By the way I have added bug to VSOnline and they are working on it. Today I will try to do as you have recomended, but not sure that it help as the issue is not reproducable all the time.